# Simple write in processing

Tags: processing

Here is a piece of code i wrote in processing.

```java
{   import processing.serial.*;
    Serial myPort;  
    // Create object from Serial class int val;  
    // Data received from the serial port 
    void setup()  {   size(860, 860);
    // I know that the first port in the serial list on my mac   
    // is always my  FTDI adaptor, so I open Serial.list()[0].   
    // On Windows machines, this generally opens COM1.   
    // Open whatever port is the one you're using.   String portName = Serial.list()[1];

    myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600); 

}  

void draw() {   
    background(255);    
    if ((mouseX >100)&&(mouseY>50)&&(mousePressed))
    {  
        // If mouse is over square,     fill(204);                      
        // change color and     myPort.write('U');  
        // send an H to indicate mouse is over square     println("U");         }   rect(100, 50, 100, 100);         // UP        if ((mousePressed)&&(mouseX>50)&&(mouseY>200)) {  // If mouse is over square,     fill(204);
                // change color and     myPort.write('L');      // send an H to indicate mouse is over square     println("L");          } rect(50, 200, 100, 100);//LEFT    
    if ((mousePressed)&&(mouseX>180)&&(mouseY>200)){  // If mouse is over square,     fill(204);               
        // change color and     myPort.write('R');  
        // send an H to indicate mouse is over square     println("R");
    }  
    rect(180, 200, 100, 100);
    //RIGHT     
    if ((mousePressed)&&(mouseX>100)&&(mouseY>350)) {  // If mouse is over square,     fill(204);     
        // change color and     myPort.write('B');   
        // send an H to indicate mouse is over square     println("B");  
    }
    rect(100, 350, 100, 100);//BACK
}
}
```

I wanted to send the outputs U,L,R,B across the serial port whenever the mouseover is on any of the 4 boxes like. top box U, Bottom box D, Left box L and so on. but i get ULD instead of D, LUL instead of L and various other haphazard outputs. Please help. And please ignore the comments in my code.. Thank you

Comment: Please present your  code in an organized and more readable manner

Comment: How? Sorry, I just joined SO.

Comment: Your code is illegible. Please reformat it and indent all of it starting at 4 spaces from the left to display correctly here.

Comment: Just add some new lines (press enter) at the end of each statement (after each semicolon). Then make sure to keep 4 spaces before each line so that all those lines will be shown as code

Comment: Is this okay? @ImeshaSudasingha

Comment: Right now your code isn't really readable. Look at the code in your post, and then look at the  code in your editor. Are they the same? The code in your post looks like it has a bunch of lines on a single line, which is commented out. That's not what you're running, is it? To fix this, edit your post, and copy in the code from your editor. Highlight it, and press the code button. That will preserve formatting. Also, you'll have better luck if you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - just use basic `println()` statements instead of adding Arduino code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a section of your code. This is the first if statement in your `draw()` function:

```java
  if ((mouseX >100)&&(mouseY>50)&&(mousePressed))
  {       
    println("U");
  }
```

Please take a careful look at this code and try to describe what the logic will do. You check if `mouseX > 100` and `mouseY > 50`. But that will be true even if the mouse is in the lower-right corner of your window! Presumably you don't want the "up" button to be pressed when you click in the lower-right corner of the window.

This flaw in your logic is what's causing multiple messages to be sent. You aren't restricting your mouse position enough. You're only checking against the **top** and **left** edges of the buttons. You also have to check against the **right** and **bottom** edges of the buttons. This if statement might look something like this:

```java
if(mousePressed && mouseX > 100 && mouseX < 200 && mouseY > 50 && mouseY < 150){
   println("U");
}
```

There is a [Button example](https://www.processing.org/examples/button.html) that comes with the Processing editor. Just go to `File` > `Examples` and then look for the `Button` example.

Also, you might want to start using the [mouseClicked()](https://www.processing.org/reference/mouseClicked_.html) and related functions instead of doing everything from the `draw()` function. Presumably you don't want to continually send "U" 60 times per second while the mouse is pressed down. Using `mouseClicked()` will help you isolate a single mouse event.